# Using OntProperty and DatatypeProperty - Jena Ontology

Tags: java, semantics, jena, ontology

```
    OntModel onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(
            OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM_MICRO_RULE_INF, null );

    String inputFileName = "./src/test.xml";    

    InputStream in = FileManager.get().open(inputFileName);
    if (in == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "File: " + inputFileName + " not found");
    }

    onto.read(new InputStreamReader(in), "");        

    //ns is the namespace...
    OntClass userClass = onto.getOntClass(ns+"User");

    Individual dada = onto.createIndividual(ns+"Daryl", userClass);

    Property prefBathtub = onto.getProperty(ns+"prefersBathtub");
    Property prefBathtubWt = onto.getProperty(ns+"prefersBathtubWeight");

    dada.addLiteral(prefBathtub, true);
    dada.addLiteral(prefBathtubWt, 0.30);

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("./src/test2.xml");
    onto.write( out, "RDF/XML"); // readable rdf/xml
    out.close();
```

How do I use OntProperty and/or DatatypeProperty instead of just Property?

By using Property do I get the same amount of expressiveness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an `ObjectProperty` object from an ontology model, use [`OntModel.getObjectProperty`()](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/com/hp/hpl/jena/ontology/OntModel.html#getObjectProperty%28java.lang.String%29). Likewise for datatype properties, etc. The `Ont` classes are more expressive in the sense that they contain convenience API for getting, for example, the super-properties of a property, with one method call. However, as the convenience API only accesses the underlying triples in the graph, there is strictly speaking nothing you can do with an `ObjectProperty` that you can't do with a `Property`. It's just harder work!

Incidentally, Jena allows you to access other facets of an underlying RDF resource with the `.as()` method. So:

```
Property p = myModel.getProperty( "http://example.com/foo#p" );
OntProperty op = p.as( OntProperty.class );
```

Comment: The .as() method you mentioned is a convenient "casting"-like tool for making it an OntProperty. Thanks Ian!